# How are ClassTags made available in Scala?

Tags: scala, implicit, classtag

With

```
def fn[T: ClassTag](...)
```

there needs to be an implicit ClassTag[T] available. How are these made available? Is there a list somewhere of ClassTags? I see an `implicit val c: ClassTag[Any]` wouldn't cut it as ClassTag is nonvariant. And how are ClassTags made available for custom classes? For example, in

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
class A
def fn[T: ClassTag](e: T) = Array.fill[T](1)(e)
fn(new A())
```

where is ClassTag[A] coming from? This code compiles without me defining one.

Searching for implicits in Predef and the reflection package in the source code didn't help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is in the [documentation](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~hmiller/scaladoc/library/scala/reflect/ClassTag.html) for the class:

> If an implicit value of type u.ClassTag[T] is required, the compiler will make one up on demand.